# Unable to upload image from android phone storage to facebook with caption in cordova android

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, image-uploading

I'm using the facebookconnect plugin from github to upload images to my timeline on facebook.
Now i'm able to upload the image form a web url using the feed method by specifying the link.
However it shows error when i use the link for the picture as file:///path to img/img1.png.
Also it is important that i use a caption for the image.
The image exists in my phone storage.

The function i'm using to upload now is:

```
function imgshare()
{

var z = 'http://33.media.tumblr.com/4f057b48f29f3c167a962380d1a35443/tumblr_mgofxc3zhm1qfwg0ho1_500.jpg';
n='Enjoy Life';
var options = { method:"feed",
                        picture: z,
                        name:n,
                        caption:'Shared via app',
                        description:'This is an image shared from my app'};



    facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(options,
                                    function (result) {
                                        alert("Posted. " + JSON.stringify(result));                               
 },
                                    function (e) {
                                        alert("Failed: " + e);
                                    });

  }
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Picture has to be min of 200px by 200px and remote you can't use a local image.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2

also put a "var" in font of n.. i.e.

var n = 'Enjoy Life';

other then that it all looks like it would work. I tested this very thing today and it was fine.

Comment: The above code works fine, the problem is that i'm not able to use the path to an image on my phone in place of the url (ie, z).

Comment: Mark Philip D'santos: have you find solution of your problem? i am facing the same issue/